# Did I just commit shirk?

Tags: allah, shirk, religion

Yesterday I had a thought (but I don’t know if it was waswas or me) about how if I was an atheist and I had two options being a Muslim or a Christian. And in my head I thought if I was an atheist and I barley knew anything from both religions at first hand I would probably pick being a Christian because it looks much easier (keep in mind this is not how I feel now I would NEVER convert to being a Christian or Catholic I believe in Allah and the Quran). So if this thought was from me (not from waswas) would it be considered shirk even though this is not how I feel now.

As soon as I got this thought I regretted it . This is why I think this is waswas

Comment: Just the thought of it wont make you a shirk. Shirk is when you ni'at and there is a disbelief or belief in the diety of Allah. However, it is advisable that you keep away from all this thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Salam alaikum dear Brother,

No, you are still Muslim and this was a bad try by the satan.

Keep Waswasa away from you by making a lot of Dhikr.

Learn something about your religion from traditional sources for example: [www.seekersguidance.com](http://www.seekersguidance.com)

Our religion is a mercy and a blessing in all life areas, be it economy, marriage, or even in travelling. May Allah guide you to what is beloved to him.